# numpy fail to run on Big Sur 11.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy

Recently, Numpy within my Python installation stopped working.

I believe that this was likely caused by my Mac upgrading to Xcode 12.5.1 (which got updated on 23/06/2021).

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 03:36:27) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.0"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

I no longer have /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib on my system:

```
ls: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib: No such file or directory
```

However, [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655588) seems to be expected with Big Sur. I seem to be the only one impacted by this so far with numpy... why is this?

I tried reinstalling numpy from pip3 (source and wheel) and from brew, but the outcome is always the same.

here is my system:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.4
BuildVersion:   20F71
```

Answer (score 1):

My similar error was fixed by removing Kite. For some reason the application is causing issues when importing numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by running

```
pip3 install numpy --no-binary numpy
```