# Yet another numpy import failure question

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I normally use Pycharm and have no problem importing numpy.

If I invoke the same virtual environment on the mac terminal command line, I get:

```
(segment_venv) Joes-MBP:MyProject joe$ python wtf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joe/PycharmProjects/MyProject/wtf.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

How do I get this to work on the command line?

Comment: When you say "the same virtual environment", did you copy the whole environment over from the other system, or did you build it up by installing?  You can't copy virtual environments directly, because `numpy` has some parts that have to be compiled, and Linux binaries don't work on MacOS.  Did you read the tips, as suggested?

Comment: @TimRoberts  No, in both cases, the same virtual environment is being invoked: ```/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv```.  I'm not copying it.  I did look at the tips.  Nothing obvious comes to mind (but I'm no expert....)

Comment: This might come from having two different gcc's installed.  Check here for a suggestion:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189249/numpy-fail-to-run-on-big-sur-11-4

Comment: Had a look at that link.  I have ```/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib``` on my machine.  I tried ```pip3 install numpy --no-binary numpy``` which gave rise to a new error: ```dlopen(/Users/joe/VirtualEnvironments/segment_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3```